# Open image from Camera and save it loses quality

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera

I have a problem, when I take a picture from my camera, I save the image by directly passing the parameter of the target folder.

```
    takePictureIntent.putExtra("output", uriSavedImage);
```

This picture is saved with the maximum quality.
But if I open this picture, when I save it, even if I set to the maximum quality (100 if it's JPEG), the saved image loses quality and dimensions.

Anyone have this problem?

```
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    File file = new File(this.photosPath, this.photoTakedAltered);

    try {
          outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
          this.photoFilteredBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
          outStream.flush();
          outStream.close();
```

Comment: Do you also resize the picture?

Comment: Thanks, but I finaly realized what's the problem. In some part of the code I'm creating an option to the Bitmap: inSampleSize = 7. When I remove this, the problem is solved.